Какой фреймворк на python использовать для написания админ панели приложения? Я использую FastAPI с psycopg2 postgres
Пишу приложение на python использую fastapi и psycopg2 для соединения с БД postgres. Подскажите, какой фреймворк лучше подойдет для соединения с такой БД

Так на фастапи и пиши дальше

он как будто под это не особо заточен у него нет инструментов для графических админпанелей,  я думал фласк использовать, но он через орм работает, немного коряво с такой бд писать. может есть интереснее решения

Django... но это 2 шага назад в технологиях и дублирование типов данных ещё раз.

Формочки на nuxt+vue-любой-ui-фреймворк можно наделать.

flask не через orm работает, в нем можно orm использовать, а можно и не использовать, точно так же как и в fastapi. Можно посмотреть готовый пример fastapi с дашбордом от автора fastapi: https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-template. В целом - соединение с базой и админка это два разных вопроса.

У того же Flask нет никакой встроенной админки и ORM. FastAPI от него в этом плане ничем не отличается. Это только Django выделяется из всех фреймворков наличием батареек на все случаи жизни (в том числе админки и ORM). Если хочется как в Django - проще взять Django.

Исполуйте Django
